# Campo Saldo en base a Retiro y Deposito SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente *script*:

```sql
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE = '2023-04-01'
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE    = '2023-04-14'
DECLARE @SaldoInicial NUMERIC(18,2) = 14.38

SELECT 
 t2.FECHA
,t2.DESCRIPCION
,t2.RETIRO
,t2.DEPOSITO
,@SaldoInicial

FROM dbo.Transacciones2 t2

WHERE t2.FECHA BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin
```

Me da el siguiente resultado

```
FECHA       DESCRIPCION                                  RETIRO     DEPOSITO    SaldoInicial
2023-04-01  TRANSFERENCIA INTERNA A: 46110004855         10000.00                  14.38    
2023-04-01  TSP                                          20.00                     14.38    
2023-04-01  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            100000.00      14.38    
2023-04-01  RETIRO CUENTA CORRIENTE                      200.00                    14.38    
2023-04-01  T.S.P.                                       2.00                      14.38    
2023-04-01  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            13680.00       14.38    
2023-04-01  EMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES            80000.00                  14.38    
2023-04-01  COMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES           150.00                    14.38    
2023-04-01  T.S.P. EMISION CHEQUE 2239                   160.00                    14.38    
2023-04-03  COMPRA DE DIVISAS EFECTIVO CUENTA                       1934.62        14.38    
2023-04-03  VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA               1209.14                   14.38    
2023-04-03  COMISION CAJA                                6.05                      14.38    
2023-04-03  VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA               1209.14                   14.38    
2023-04-03  COMISION CAJA                                6.05                      14.38    
2023-04-05  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            1000.00        14.38
```

Lo que quiero es agregar un campo que se llame Saldo, el cual vaya restando si es un retiro o sumando si es un depósito en base al saldo inicial.

Este es el resultado que espero:

```
FECHA       DESCRIPCION                                  RETIRO     DEPOSITO    SaldoInicial   Saldo
2023-04-01  TRANSFERENCIA INTERNA A: 46110004855                    10000.00       14.38      1,014.38
2023-04-01  TSP                                          20.00                     14.38        994.38
2023-04-01  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            100000.00      14.38    100,994.38
2023-04-01  RETIRO CUENTA CORRIENTE                      200.00                    14.38    100,794.38
2023-04-01  T.S.P.                                       2.00                      14.38    100,792.38
2023-04-01  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            13680.00       14.38    114,472.38
2023-04-01  EMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES            80000.00                  14.38     34,472.38
2023-04-01  COMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES           150.00                    14.38     34,322.38
2023-04-01  T.S.P. EMISION CHEQUE 2239                   160.00                    14.38     34,162.38
2023-04-03  COMPRA DE DIVISAS EFECTIVO CUENTA                       1934.62        14.38        36,097
2023-04-03  VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA               1209.14                   14.38     34,887.86
2023-04-03  COMISION CAJA                                6.05                      14.38     34,881.81
2023-04-03  VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA               1209.14                   14.38     33,672.67
2023-04-03  COMISION CAJA                                6.05                      14.38     33,666.62
2023-04-05  DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE                            1000.00        14.38     34,666.62
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar una función de ventana `sum()` con una cláusula `over order by` para ir *arrastrando* la suma de depósitos y retiros y así calcular una columna de saldo.

Por ejemplo:

```
select   t2.FECHA
       , t2.DESCRIPCION
       , t2.RETIRO
       , t2.DEPOSITO
       , @SaldoInicial SaldoIni
       , @SaldoInicial + SUM(coalesce(t2.deposito, 0) - coalesce(t2.retiro, 0)) over (order by fecha, orden) Saldo
  from Transacciones2 t2
 where t2.fecha between @FechaInicio and @FechaFin
```

En mis pruebas, dado que la fecha no tiene información de fecha y hora y para que la consulta siempre devuelva la misma información, he utilizado una hipotética columna llamada `orden` para incluir en el `order by`.

Con tus datos de prueba, me ha dado el resultado:

```
FECHA      DESCRIPCION                          RETIRO     DEPOSITO   SaldoIni Saldo     
---------- ------------------------------------ ---------- ---------- -------- ----------
2023-04-01 TRANSFERENCIA INTERNA A: 46110004855 NULL       10000.00   14.38    10014.38
2023-04-01 TSP                                  20.00      NULL       14.38    9994.38
2023-04-01 DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE         NULL       100000.00  14.38    109994.38
2023-04-01 RETIRO CUENTA CORRIENTE              200.00     NULL       14.38    109794.38
2023-04-01 T.S.P.                               2.00       NULL       14.38    109792.38
2023-04-01 DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE         NULL       13680.00   14.38    123472.38
2023-04-01 EMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES    80000.00   NULL       14.38    43472.38
2023-04-01 COMIS.CHEQUES DE GERENCIA CLIENTES   150.00     NULL       14.38    43322.38
2023-04-01 T.S.P. EMISION CHEQUE 2239           160.00     NULL       14.38    43162.38
2023-04-03 COMPRA DE DIVISAS EFECTIVO CUENTA    NULL       1934.62    14.38    45097.00
2023-04-03 VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA       1209.14    NULL       14.38    43887.86
2023-04-03 COMISION CAJA                        6.05       NULL       14.38    43881.81
2023-04-03 VENTA DE DIVISAS CUENTA CUENTA       1209.14    NULL       14.38    42672.67
2023-04-03 COMISION CAJA                        6.05       NULL       14.38    42666.62
2023-04-05 DEPOSITO EN CUENTA CORRIENTE         NULL       1000.00    14.38    43666.62

(15 rows affected)
```

El saldo difiere, pero después de una revisión rápida, creo que el error está en la pregunta. El de la respuesta me parece correcto.

**Edición**

Si no existe una columna con la cuál se pueda asegurar el orden, haría falta dejar solo la columna de fecha en el orden, pero en ese caso agregar una cláusula `rows` para que sea capaz de calcular el saldo para cada fila (dado que hay valores que se repiten en la columna del ordenamiento).

La consulta que produce el resultado quedaría así, entonces:

```sql
select   t2.FECHA
       , t2.DESCRIPCION
       , t2.RETIRO
       , t2.DEPOSITO
       , @SaldoInicial SaldoIni
       , @SaldoInicial + SUM(coalesce(t2.deposito, 0) - coalesce(t2.retiro, 0)) over (order by fecha rows unbounded preceding) Saldo
  from Transacciones2 t2
 where t2.fecha between @FechaInicio and @FechaFin
```

El resultado sería el equivalente. Al no estar definido el orden, las transacciones de un mismo día pueden aparecer en distinto orden y eso está bien, de acuerdo al estándar. La buena noticia es que el saldo al final del día siempre va a ser consistente.

Gracias a @Luis Cazares por apuntar esto en sus comentarios.

Comment: En vez de añadir una columna hipotética, es mejor usar la opción `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` dentro del `OVER`.

Comment: @Luis, la columna hipotética (que podría ser un ID en la vida real, por ejemplo) es para que el resultado tenga siempre el mismo orden. Consideraría un defecto del sistema que me dé estados de cuenta con las transacciones en distinto orden alguna vez. No veo cómo el `rows unbounded preceding` nos ayudaría con eso.

Comment: El detalle es que hay ocasiones en las que ese orden no existe y no es relevante. El generar una columna que asigne ese orden (el cual además no está incluido en el ORDER BY) tampoco soluciona nada. El uso de `ROWS` permite que se haga la sumatoria por fila y no por fecha sin tener que generar una columna adicional.

Comment: Entiendo que hay ocasiones en que no hay orden o no es relevante. Quizás mi redacción no es clara; no estoy generando ninguna columna adicional, solo estoy sugiriendo que se use si hay una disponible. Si no la hay, no queda de otra que utilizar solo la fecha.

Comment: @LuisCazares. al final edité la pregunta y añadí la consulta si no existiera una columna por la cual ordenar. Gracias por el comentario, considero que la respuesta ha tenido una mejora que era muy necesaria gracia a este. Un saludo.